# HTML5 canvas (Animate CC) remove movieclip from stage with button

Tags: html, html5-canvas, createjs, removechild, animate-cc

please help, I have spent a whole morning trying to figure this out and have failed miserably.

I am trying to update an old swf file into a new html canvas.

So far I have updated everything including loading my desired movieclip Image_1 onto the stage into var "fl_MyInstance" this is loaded through button_1 via the following code..

---

```
this.button_1.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler()
{
    var fl_MyInstance = new lib.Image_1();
    fl_MyInstance.x = 364.70;      
    fl_MyInstance.y = 199.30;       
    this.addChild(fl_MyInstance);

}
```

---

When this movieclip is on stage it has a button within that is labelled close1 and I have tried many many codes to try and close it.... but it just isn't working.

The latest code I tried is..

```
this.close1.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));
function fl_MouseClickHandler()
{
  stage.removeChild( fl_MyInstance );
}
```

Please help, I arrived at this as I know it perhaps needs to target a parent or reference the stage or root or something, but everything tried does nothing.  I don't even mind clearing all children if necessary.

Hopefully somebody can help.

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is to do with scope.  Try the following in a new file.  Draw two movieclips on the stage and name them buttonAdd and buttonRemove.  In your library have a movie clip named Rectangle.  Now add the following code:

```
var that = this;
this.buttonAdd.addEventListener("click", addFromLibrary);
this.buttonRemove.addEventListener("click", removeClip);

function addFromLibrary(e)
{   
    window.myRectangle = stage.addChild(new lib.Rectangle());
}

function removeClip(e){
    stage.removeChild(myRectangle);
}
```

This should work but there are probably more elegant ways of achieving this.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I will try this when I am back on my computer. The close button is within the movieclip itself though, hopefully that should still work.

Comment: Hey,

I tried the following code attached to the close button within the movie clip Image_1 which was loaded inside the Var called fl_MyInstance

this.close1.addEventListener("click", removeClip);
function removeClip(e){
    stage.removeChild(fl_MyInstance);
}

Nothing happened still.

Comment: Hi, if your button is inside a movieclip you would need to tell the code to look up a level to find the movie clip to remove, try:   this.parent.removeChild(fl_MyInstance);

Comment: Thank you I will try this at the weekend :) I have been discovering there are limitations to the canvas where it made more sense to build the concept another way. But the load/close movieclip will still come in handy for other projects